# DocuSign Data Label connection to 2nd Tab only works on the same page as the original Tab

Tags: docusignapi

I've started creating a template that asks for a persons contact information on multiple pages. I've attached 2 different documents. I added all my Tabs to the first document and when I made the Tabs on the 2nd documents and wanted to connect the information view the Data Label so the person doesn't need to write the same information twice it doesn't work. If I move the tab onto the same page the original tab is on the connection appears... I move it back on the next page and it disappears again...

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Things I've tried to correct the problem:

1- copy the template, same issue
2- create a new template with different files, same issue
3- upload a template from another account that I know works, same issue

I spoke to a DocuSign support person yesterday and they were at a loss, but also at the end of their shift so they will call me back, but I thought I'd take a chance here.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Settings -> Sending Settings -> "Automatically replicate information in fields with the same data label".  You want the value to be "on all documents in an envelope".  Note that this affects all envelopes sent from this account and cannot be set on an individual envelope basis.

Comment: omg! You are amazing! I've been on the phone with DocuSign support for 2 days now, over 3 hours worth of time spent on the phone with them! The guy even asked his manager and escalated the case and they couldn't figure it out! I knew it was something so small and simple!! Thank you sooo much! Problem fixed!